# Input data for capture-mark-recapture (CMR) in package: marked

Tags: r

I am trying  to get abundance estimates of rodents for my survey area using capture mark recapture. I am using the package "marked" but keep running into a problem where my capture histories are changed to numbers eg. 0010 becomes 10.

I have tried csv's, txt files, changing numbers to text in excel and can't seem to come right. When I am able to get data into R as a capture history as opposed to a number I get "Incorrect ch values in data:10;FMU".

I think the error lies in the input data, and I'm wondering if anyone perhaps has an example of their input data for something similar?
Any suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Maybe try `read.table` or `read.csv` with argument  `colClasses = "character"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas This was exceptionally helpful, thank you! It now runs with a txt.